# 2014 SQL Server Connection to different PC on local network. VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, tcp, sql-server-2014

I trying to connect to an instance of 2014 SQL Server on Windows Server 2012 R2 standard over a local network without any success.

1. I have gone into Configuration manager and enabled TCP/IP.
2. I have gone into advanced settings on the server firewall and added new inbound     rules for all the SQL Server used TCP ports,

> 135,1433,1434,2382,2383,4022

3. I have enabled sa authentication and set a new password.

My connection string looks like this.

```
sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
              "Data Source=ServerName;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=Staff_Manager;" & _
              "User Id=sa;" & _
              "Password=myPassword;" & _
              "INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI;"
```

But , I get this error when trying to connect.

> [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or
>   access denied

I checked the Databases name and password and that is correct.

So I tried the Microsoft workaround found here, [Bug #: 471480 (SQL Server 8.0)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888228)

And I came up with this connection string,

```
sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
              "Persist Security Info=False;" & _
              "User Id=sa;" & _
              "Data Source=tcp:192.192.1.111,1433;"
```

But, I am still getting the same error. Anyone point me in the right direction as I have run out of solutions.

Comment: Check two things first, Is the Server configured to allow remote connections. If it is a named instance and not listening to the port 1433, see whether SQL server browser service is enabled or not.

Comment: @Jasqlg the browser service is enabled. Not sure what you mean with the named instance? I thought every instance is named? Or am I miss understanding things?

Comment: There are two kinds of instances we can create.Default and named. Run this against your server. SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName'). If the result is null then Default, if not then Named. You can even check the service name. it would be MSSQLSERVER for default one and someother incase of named insatnace.

Comment: For named instances, add the instance name in connection string like "Data Source=ServerName\YourInstancename;"

Comment: @Jasqlg, I found that I had needed to allow listen all in the TCP/IP. But your help was invaluable in coming to this conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference to people who also get stuck.

I found the answer was in Server Configuration Manager under SQL Server Network Configuration `TCP/IP` settings under properties on the Protocol tab. There is `Listen All` feature which I had set to "No", setting it to "yes" allowed the following connection strings to work.

```
sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
              "Data Source=190.190.1.100,1433;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=DBNameHere;" & _
              "User Id=sa;" & _
              "Password=yourPassword;"
```

Or

```
sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
              "Data Source=yourServerName;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=DBNameHere;" & _
              "User Id=sa;" & _
              "Password=yourPassword;"
```

Both strings work and are tested on a local network.